# Where is GridStreamerWindow<Event> Event type info specified

Tags: gridgain

In the Gridgain 6.0 streamer example StreamingCheckInExample.java, two windows are defined in the config.xml file. In the following code, the event type for the window is of type LocationInfo. I am wondering where is the window event type info specified?

```
private static class DetectPlacesStage implements GridStreamerStage<CheckInEvent> {
    ...

    @Nullable @Override public Map<String, Collection<?>> run(GridStreamerContext ctx,
        Collection<CheckInEvent> evts) throws GridException {
        GridStreamerWindow<LocationInfo> win = ctx.window(name());
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`GridStreamerWindow` has type parameter which is the type of the events passed to streamer. Method to get window in `GridStreamerContext` has the following signature:

`public <E> GridStreamerWindow<E> window();` Which makes possible to get window working with event types you need.

Events get to the window when you pass them to GridStreamer:

`public void addEvent(Object evt, Object... evts) throws GridException;`

Events instantiation is under user control. So, user knows what type is expected in the window.

Please let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So if I understand correctly, since the Spring container is declared scope="singleton" in the config file, if the window() of event type E, is called first time, a queue of type E will be created in the container to store events of type E. Then the same "singleton" queue will be returned whenever the method window() of event type E is called.

Comment: Spring container is used to configure GridGain (you can also create `GridConfiguration` object and pass it to `GridGain.start()`). So, streamer starts with fully configured set of windows, indexes, etc. And, yes, the same instance will be returned - the first one defined in the configuration. See also `public <E> GridStreamerWindow<E> window(String winName)`.